# ms speech from command line

Tags: cmd, text-to-speech

Is there a way to use the MS Speech utility from command line?  I can do it on a mac, but can't find any reference to it on Windows XP.

Comment: Relevant: https://askubuntu.com/questions/53896/natural-sounding-text-to-speech

Comment: Relevant: https://askubuntu.com/questions/21811/how-can-i-install-and-use-text-to-speech-software

Answer (score 75, accepted):

My 2 cents on the topic, command line one-liners:

- on Win8+ ([WinXP](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/installing-powershell-on-windows-xp-and-copying-files/)) using `PowerShell.exe`

  ```
    PowerShell -Command "Add-Type –AssemblyName System.Speech; (New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer).Speak('hello');"
  ```
- on Win using `mshta.exe` (might not be available in corp. env.)

  ```
    mshta vbscript:Execute("CreateObject(""SAPI.SpVoice"").Speak(""Hello"")(window.close)")
  ```
- on OSX using `say`

  ```
    say "hello"
  ```
- Ubuntu Desktop (>=2015) using native `spd-say`

  ```
    spd-say "hello"
  ```
- on any other Linux

  - refer to [How to text-to-speech output using command-line?](https://askubuntu.com/a/501917)
  - commandline function [using google TTS](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/13612/googles-text-to-speech-in-command-line) (wget to mp3->mplayer)
  - command using google [with mplayer directly](https://elinux.org/RPi_Text_to_Speech_(Speech_Synthesis)#Google_Text_to_Speech):

    - `/usr/bin/mplayer -ao alsa -really-quiet -noconsolecontrols "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&client=tw-ob&q=Hello%20World&tl=en"`;
- on Raspberry Pi, Win, OSX (or any remote) using *Node-Red*

  `npm i node-red-contrib-sysmessage`

Comment: Wow this is an AWESOME answer

Comment: When I run the mshta command, I get an Access is Denied response.

Comment: @ColorCodin sounds like, you need to run it in an elevated environment. Like running "cmd.exe as Administrator" or granting access to mshta.exe for all users.

Comment: How can I change audio output device on Windows using mshta.exe ?

Comment: @MacMarde you would search stackoverflow for "vbscript change audio input" or something similiar

Comment: I can verify that the liners for OSX and Win-PS work for me. When I attempted with Win-CMD, no audio was generated. - Why is it?

Comment: @Azhar since `mshta.exe` is a very old way of calling scripts, might be security restrictions on Win10/Win11 - pwershell is the modern way to go.

Comment: Some of us have our own preferred shells which aren't powershell — mshta worked fine or me under Windows 10!

Comment: @ClioCJS It does not matter, which shell you use to call the powershell.exe on windows from. Works also from git-bash or wsl or pwsh. Since powershell is preinstalled, it should always be available on windows 8+.

Comment: @BananaAcid At no point did i run powershell to invoke mshta.exe under my command line.   That's my point: Some of us don't use powershell, don't want to, and mshta.exe lets us do this, and works just fine under windows 10.  But thank you for mis-explaining my own situation to me as if I was so stupid as to call powershell from my command line and not realize that's what I'm doing.

Comment: I am sorry, it seems my explanation was not not written well enough, let me try to rewrite it (so it may also be helpful to others): 1. It is possible to run the powershell.exe from any other shell on windows (may it be cmd or git-bash or whichever) by executing the above command. You do not need to use a powershell to run the powershell.exe for this single line.  2. access to mshta may be limited any may not be available in a corporate environment on win8 and win10 / and might be missing. Powershell is available. I am sorry, if my explanation offended you. @ClioCJS

Answer (score 25):

There's a nice open source program that does what you're asking for on Windows called Peter's Text to Speech available here: http://jampal.sourceforge.net/ptts.html

It contains a binary called ptts.exe that will speak text from standard input, so you can run it like this:

```
echo hello there | ptts.exe
```

Alternatively, you could use the following three line VBS script to get similar basic TTS:

```
'say.vbs
set s = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
s.Speak Wscript.Arguments(0), 3
s.WaitUntilDone(1000)
```

And you could invoke that from the command line like this:

```
cscript say.vbs "hello there"
```

If you go the script route, you'll probably want to find some more extensive code examples with a variable timeout and error handling.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You can install Peter's Text to Speech program, [Jampal](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jampal/files/jampal/) and then execute the ptts.vbs file to play text files. The voices you choose need to be installed already in Windows.

Example:

`C:\Program Files\Jampal>cscript "c:\program files\jampal\ptts.vbs" -voice "IVONA Amy" < raven.txt`

and

`C:\Program Files\Jampal>cscript "c:\program files\jampal\ptts.vbs" -voice "IVONA Jennifer" < raven.txt`

Answer (score 5):

There's also *Balabolka*: http://www.cross-plus-a.com/bconsole.htm
It has a command line tool `balcon.exe`. You can use it like this:

1. List voices:

   ```
    balcon.exe -l
   ```
2. Speak file:

   ```
    balcon.exe -n "IVONA 2 Jennifer" -f file.txt
   ```
3. Speak from the command-line:

   ```
    balcon.exe -n "IVONA 2 Jennifer" -t "hello there"
   ```

More command line options are available. I tried it on Ubuntu with SAPI5 installed in Wine. It works just fine.

Comment: Balabolka is cool. It does the job and nothing else, you can configure the hell out of the voice. And it's alive, I just downloaded the new version. So yes, this is an upvote situation.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't find a command you can always wrap the [System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer(v=vs.110).aspx) from .Net 3.0 (Don't forget to reference "System.Speech")

```
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace Talk
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var ss = new SpeechSynthesizer())
                foreach (var toSay in args)
                    ss.Speak(toSay);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: using github.com/oleg-shilo/cs-script this can be used from commandline without compiling and without visual studio

Answer (score 4):

There is a powershell way also:

Create a file called speak.ps1

```
param([string]$inputText)
Add-Type –AssemblyName System.Speech 
$synth = New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
$synth.Speak($inputText);
```

Then you can call it

```
.\speak.ps1 "I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
rem The user decides what to convert here
 :input
 cls
 echo Type in what you want the computer to say and then press the enter key.
 echo.
 set /p text=

 rem Making the temp file
 :num
 set num=%random%
 if exist temp%num%.vbs goto num
 echo ' > "temp%num%.vbs"
 echo set speech = Wscript.CreateObject("SAPI.spVoice") >> "temp%num%.vbs"
 echo speech.speak "%text%" >> "temp%num%.vbs"
 start temp%num%.vbs
 pause
 del temp%num%.vbs
 goto input



pause
```

Answer (score 2):

Your best approach is to write a small command line utility that will do it for you. It would not be a lot of work - just read text in and then use the ms tts library.

Another alternative is to use [Cepstral](http://cepstral.com/). It comes with a nice command line utility and sounds light years better than the ms tts.

Answer (score 1):

I use [wsay](https://github.com/p-groarke/wsay), it's small and more close to `say` in macos.