# Python: Making a beep noise

Tags: python, audio, serial-port

I'm trying to get the program to give me a beeping noise. I'm on a windows machine. I've looked at http://docs.python.org/library/winsound.html

But not sure how I can program this with a barcode scanner.

Here is my code for the serial barcode scanner.

```
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 9600

#for windows
ser.port = 2 #for COM3

ser.open()
ser.write('hello')
ser.close()
```

UPDATE: Since I'm annoying my co-workers with the beep. Can I get it to come through the audio jack for headphones?

Comment: You want the barcode scanner to make the noise or the windows machine it's connected too?

Comment: the windows machine. I think the barcode scanner will do it by itself

Comment: Re "Update": Yep, it's a well-known fact that beeps are annoying :)

Comment: @CharlieParker because win sound is for windows. Print "\a" instead.

Comment: Not sure about Windows, but on Linux, there's the command-line program called `play` that will play MP3s if you want to just record a compressed audio beep. You can probably get an equivalent for Windows.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

On Windows, if you want to just make the computer make a beep sound:

```
import winsound
frequency = 2500  # Set Frequency To 2500 Hertz
duration = 1000  # Set Duration To 1000 ms == 1 second
winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
```

The `winsound.Beep()` can be used wherever you want the beep to occur.

Comment: This one is neat: `def annoy():
    for i in range(1, 10):
            winsound.Beep(i * 100, 200)`

Comment: Or `def sos():
     for i in range(0, 3):
             winsound.Beep(2000, 100)
     for i in range(0, 3):
             winsound.Beep(2000, 400)
     for i in range(0, 3):
             winsound.Beep(2000, 100)`. I should probably go back to work now :D

Comment: On windows winsound.Beep is carried across windows Sounds.

Comment: I am on Mac, can't find this on pip repo?

Comment: winsound is a windows specific library

Comment: Only bad thing with this, is that there is no way to control the volume.

Answer (score 194):

The cross-platform way to do this is to `print('\a')`. This will send the ASCII Bell character to stdout, and will hopefully generate a beep (a for 'alert'). Note that many modern terminal emulators provide the option to ignore bell characters.

Since you're on Windows, you'll be happy to hear that Windows has its own (brace yourself) *Beep API*, which allows you to send beeps of arbitrary length and pitch. Note that this is a Windows-only solution, so you should probably prefer `print('\a')` unless you really care about Hertz and milliseconds.

The Beep API is accessed through the *winsound* module: http://docs.python.org/library/winsound.html

Comment: Although he asked specifically for Windows, I think this is the all around better solution, unless the WinSound API will revert to \a for OS independant. There are plenty of audio APIs as well

Comment: Frankly, I would avoid playing PC-speaker beeps altogether in a serious programming effort. If he is indeed on Windows, he should probably try to play the system theme's default "alert" signal instead. With any luck, that signal is accessible through whatever GUI package he's using.

Comment: If you use print in a console app, consider adding end="" to prevent a newline every time you beep.

Comment: @jforberg The api for that is [winsound.MessageBeep](https://docs.python.org/2/library/winsound.html#winsound.MessageBeep) which can take MB_ICONASTERISK, MB_ICONEXCLAMATION, MB_ICONHAND, MB_ICONQUESTION, and MB_OK.

Comment: Also, if you're using `curses`, you can use `curses.beep()`. Haven't tested it to see if it works in the Windows version of `curses` yet.

Comment: This doesn't work in cygwin. I have a alias set up to do "doThis && cd there && doThat && cd here && doTheOtherThing" but the problem is that doThis, doThat, and doTheOtherThing all take a while, and doThat waits for user input, so I might go off and minimize that window and go do something else, not realizing that it is waiting for me. I thought maybe I could do a quick python script because echo -ne '\007' also does not work. I dont have the ability to use winsound from the accepted answer on my machine either. Does anyone have any suggestions? or is this a new question on superuser?

Comment: @searchengine27 That's a new question

Comment: If you're using Python 3, don't forget to use parentheses or you'll get a syntax error. Use print('\a')

Comment: "If he is indeed on Windows, he should probably try to play the system theme's default "alert" signal instead. With any luck, that signal is accessible through whatever GUI package he's using." FWIW, printing a `\a` does exactly that nowadays (at least on my Win10 system).

Comment: On **MacOS** `\a` briefly dims the terminal window. A kinder, gentler beep.

Comment: '\a' does NOT play anything for me on windows.

Comment: Trying to do this in python installed in termux on android. It does not play audio but vibrates. Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: '\a' does NOT play anything for me on Windows 7. Instead, a blue bullet is printed.

Answer (score 43):

**Linux.**

```
$ apt-get install beep

$ python
>>> os.system("beep -f 555 -l 460")
```

OR

```
$ beep -f 659 -l 460 -n -f 784 -l 340 -n -f 659 -l 230 -n -f 659 -l 110 -n -f 880 -l 230 -n -f 659 -l 230 -n -f 587 -l 230 -n -f 659 -l 460 -n -f 988 -l 340 -n -f 659 -l 230 -n -f 659 -l 110 -n -f 1047 -l 230 -n -f 988 -l 230 -n -f 784 -l 230 -n -f 659 -l 230 -n -f 988 -l 230 -n -f 1318 -l 230 -n -f 659 -l 110 -n -f 587 -l 230 -n -f 587 -l 110 -n -f 494 -l 230 -n -f 740 -l 230 -n -f 659 -l 460
```

Comment: Downvoted for two reasons: first, GNU/Linux != Debian and apt-get isn't universal; second, you shouldn't use os.system, use the subprocess module instead.

Comment: As a linux user trying to get a simple and cheap beep going for when a long code finishes, this was by and far the easiest solution. I especially loved the little jingle!

Note that you may have to call "sudo modprobe pcspkr" and install beep before this option will work, according to https://askubuntu.com/questions/19906/beep-in-shell-script-not-working

Comment: `os.system` is fine, especially with a hardcoded value, not everyone is writing a webserver.

Comment: @Ben Old question, but fwiw it seems pretty harsh to downvote this. The question relates to an area with no cross-platform solution as I understand it. The accepted answer with 140 likes is Windows-specific. And you don't explain why a legitimate module is "bad" practice.

Comment: @geotheory this appears to be a typical case where adhesion to an arbitrary subset of specifics is upheld over the net (or big picture) relevance. It's highly likely any programmer who can use Linux, would know how to install packages or could easily figure it out. As for the second premise, it looks like c z might be correct in the same way as to the relevance.

Answer (score 41):

There's a Windows answer, and a Debian answer, so here's a **Mac** one:

This assumes you're just here looking for a quick way to make a customisable alert sound, and not specifically the piezeoelectric beep you get on Windows:

```
os.system( "say beep" )
```

*Disclaimer: You can replace `os.system` with a call to the `subprocess` module if you're worried about someone hacking on your beep code.*

See: [How to make the hardware beep sound in Mac OS X 10.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127977/how-to-make-the-hardware-beep-sound-in-mac-os-x-10-6)

Comment: And if you don't want to wait for say to finish terminate with an & like so: `os.system('say "your message here" &')`

Comment: Cross-platform with [these commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39647762/819417).

Answer (score 26):

I was searching for the same but for Linux shell.

The topic brought me to an answer, -thanks-

Maybe more pythonic manner :

```
import os
beep = lambda x: os.system("echo -n '\a';sleep 0.2;" * x)
beep(3)
```

Notes :

- the sleep value (here 0.2), depends on the length (seconds) of your default beep sound
- I choosed to use `os.system` rather then `subprocess.Popen` for simplicity (it could be bad)
- the '-n' for `echo` is to have no more display
- the last ';' after `sleep` is necessary for the resulting text sequence (*x)
- also tested through ssh on an X term

Comment: Python has an equivalent of both `echo` (`print`) and `sleep`, so it is actually not pythonic to go through external calls, especially when they are (non-portable) Unix calls.

Comment: what does (3) means?

Comment: @bumbumpaw the `(3)` is passed to the lambda as the `x` argument. For this  specific case, the "echo -n '\a';sleep 0.2;" string will be concatenated 3 time with itself generating the string "echo -n '\a';sleep 0.2;echo -n '\a';sleep 0.2;echo -n '\a';sleep 0.2;" before actual call to the `os.system` function.

Comment: Upvoted for the echo part (works on windows when using pythonw, while print does not). The sleep part does not work on windows (only one beep).

Answer (score 22):

I found this library to be helpful:
Install beepy,

```
pip install beepy
```

There are 6 different sound options, you can see details here: https://pypi.org/project/beepy/

Code snip to listen to all the sounds:

```
import beepy as beep
for ii in range(1,7): 
    beep.beep(ii)
```

Comment: I had an issue with `winsound.Beep(....)` in w10 (I needed to run troubleshooter to solve it each time I run `winsound.Beep(....)`), but this solved it.

Comment: @user_007 I was also getting some errors after running it the first few times. I'm not sure what the problem was but I ended up bagging it and using '\a' instead.

Comment: On windows 10 in 2022, pip install beepy fails with error installing simpleaudio

Answer (score 14):

If you want beep from Zelda or Mario theme :

```
!pip install chime
import chime
chime.theme('zelda')

chime.success()
chime.warning()
chime.error()
chime.info()
chime.notify_exceptions()

1/0
```

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. Running PyCharm on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 13):

The cross-platform way:

```
import time
import sys
for i in range(1,6):
    sys.stdout.write('\r\a{i}'.format(i=i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

Thanks to [c z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3601660/c-z):

```
print(end='\a')
```

Comment: The only important part of this is `sys.stdout.write('\a')`

Comment: @jstrieb -- this is a tiny standalone program. Its importance in the completeness itself.

Comment: `print(end='\a')`

Comment: Does not work on windows when using `pythonw`, only `python`

Comment: Note that \a doesn't seem to make a beep on Termux.

Answer (score 7):

**On linux:** `print('\007')` will make the system bell sound.

Answer (score 5):

## Using `pygame` on any platform

The advantage of using `pygame` is that it can be made to work on any OS platform. **Below example code is for GNU/Linux** though.

First install the `pygame` module for `python3` as [**explained in detail here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42708034/2192488).

```
$ sudo pip3 install pygame
```

The `pygame` module can play `.wav` and `.ogg` files from any file location. Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/phone-incoming-call.oga')
sound.play()
```

Answer (score 3):

I have made a [package](https://github.com/kindlychung/pybeep) for that purpose.

You can use it like this:

```
from pybeep.pybeep import PyVibrate, PyBeep
PyVibrate().beep()
PyVibrate().beepn(3)
PyBeep().beep()
PyBeep().beepn(3)
```

It depends on [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) and only supports python3.

Comment: Try pip3 install pybeep.

Comment: Just know that you gotta install sox. run: brew install sox

Answer (score -1):

For all systems:

```
def beep():
  output.eval_js('new Audio("data:audio/wav;base64,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").play()')

beep()
```

Notebook developers must add a beep function to the output.

Answer (score -3):

```
# playsound in cross plate form, just install it with pip
#  first install playsound > pip install playsound
from playsound import playsound
playsound('audio.mp3')
```

Comment: While this can play the file `audio.mp3`, it doesn't really give an answer to the original question.