# Simple beep to speakers

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio

I want windows (possibly cross-platform) solution to play simple tone of certain frequency and length on **speakers**.  Here

[Python: Making a beep noise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537481/python-making-a-beep-noise)

it is suggested to use `winsound`, but this solution only creates PC speaker sound.  Is there any way to create sound on **real speakers**?

Comment: how can i do it on linux? ... better yet, portable over many platforms.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `winsound` to play

A single-frequency beep:

```
winsound.Beep(2000,500) # Hz, milliseconds
```

An external sound:

```
winsound.PlaySound('./sounds_folder/my_sound.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

Comment: I want pure frequency beep but not on system speakers but on normal speakers (attached to green exit on computer).

Comment: I have used winsound for a similar task, to send a pure sine wave to the external speakers. Once I connect the jack, the external speakers override the system speakers. Could this be a sound card-related option?

Comment: In `winsound` instructions it explicitly says that Beep uses PC speaker.

Comment: On certain systems the output that goes to PC speaker might divert to whatever overrides it: an external speaker, a bluetooth speaker. Where do you hear your normal Windows sounds if you connect the external speakers to the green jack?

Comment: I hear windows sounds on external speakers what makes things even more curious.

Comment: I just tried to `winsound.beep` a sinewave out of my bluetooth speakers, and it works as expected. This might maybe have to do with your sound card, if you use one.

Comment: On my notebook that does not have PC speaker Beep is transferred to normal speakers.  However on desktop with PC speaker Beep is always performed PC speaker and I just did not find a way to transfer signal to normal speakers.