# python code to make a beep

Tags: python, macos

I have installed Python 3.6.0 on a MacBook Pro running OSX Sierra. I would like to make a beep via `print('\a')` but it doesn't. I have looked at the various suggestions on StackOverflow, but none have caused the MacBook Pro to 'beep' - no sound at all. Please can someone explain why, and what code really does elicit a beep?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33502275/3051961

Comment: I did it on mac on the terminal and it works for me

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an IDE the reason might be that the IDE doesn't turn \a into a sound. Try open terminal, open python console then type:

```
print("\a")
```

Tested on Windows and it worked without any issue in the Python console. No sound in the IDE however.