# Motherboard beep in Python

Tags: python, audio, beep, motherboard

Is there a simple way to sounds from the "motherboard's speaker" in python ?
in fact, the computer i'am working on has no speakers

Comment: This works? https://stackoverflow.com/a/6537563/16822867

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.