# Is there a way to make the terminal blink when python script finishes running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

I created a python script to call some API. I want to be informed when it's finished. Is there a way to prevent me from checking the status in the terminal constantly? For example, Can python make the terminal blink or something when it's done?

Comment: You can play a tone when it's done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537481/python-making-a-beep-noise

Comment: So do you mean flashing the tile within the windows taskbar? If so you'd need to look at a package such as `wincom` - Alternatively (or something) have you considered a simple beep tone? https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html

Comment: also great idea! thank you, I think the print('\a') beep is genial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to flash the tray icon in Windows, and a different way to do it in Linux/Mac, but I'm not aware of an os-agnostic way of doing that.

You can pop up a window using TkInter, though.  TkInter comes with Python.

```
from tkinter import messagebox

messagebox.showinfo(title="Done", message="Dust!  This task is done.")
```

Comment: thanks bro, my script is running in the WSL2. I just tested with your sugguestion, it worked, but the script will be frozen for ca. 20-30s waiting for the WSL response

Comment: Huh!  That's interesting.  I don't run Windows here, but maybe I'll throw something together just to check that out.